# Pass Variables from MQTT to Kivy

Tags: python, kivy, navigation-drawer, mqtt, kivy-language

I try to pass values from MQTT to Kivy dashboard with a navigation drawler.

Can someone give me a hint how I can change the variables?
Here is my sample code. MQTT is working.
I use Python 3.6.6 and 1.10.1.

mainmenu.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.garden.navigationdrawer import NavigationDrawer
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt

class Drawer(NavigationDrawer):
    vartext1 = StringProperty("Button")
    vartext2 = StringProperty("Text")

class MainMenuApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Drawer()

    def on_start(self):
        topic = "kivy/#"

        def onConnect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
            mqttc.subscribe(topic, 0)

        def onMessage(client, userdata, msg):
            msg.payload = msg.payload.decode("utf-8")
            print ("[INFO   ] [MQTT        ] topic: " + msg.topic +" msg: "+ msg.payload)
            if msg.topic == "kivy/button":
                vartext1 = msg.payload

            if msg.topic == "kivy/text":
                vartext2 = msg.payload

        mqttc = mqtt.Client(client_id="kivy-client", clean_session=True)
        mqttc.on_connect      = onConnect 
        mqttc.on_message      = onMessage
        mqttc.connect("10.0.0.104", 1883, keepalive=60, bind_address="")
        mqttc.loop_start() # start loop to process callbacks! (new thread!)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainMenuApp().run()
```

mainmenu.kv

```
<Drawer>:
    # Side panel
    BoxLayout:
        padding: 30
        Button:
            text: root.vartext1
    # Main panel
    BoxLayout:
        padding: 30
        Label:
            text: root.vartext2
```

Comment: what is `toggle_state`?, please provide a [mcve]

Comment: If you click on the button2, the navigation menu pops out from the left side.

Comment: I removed the unnecessary parts from the post.

Comment: Can you accept an answer?

Answer (score 4):

You can pass "self" parameter to mqtt.Client constructor like this:

```
parameters = {'self': self}
mqttc = mqtt.Client(client_id="kivy-client", clean_session=True, userdata = parameters)
```

and now inside onMessage procedure you can access that parameters:

```
userdata['self'].vartext1 = msg.payload
```

So your mainmenu.py file should looks like that:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.garden.navigationdrawer import NavigationDrawer
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt

class Drawer(NavigationDrawer):
    vartext1 = StringProperty("Button")
    vartext2 = StringProperty("Text")

class MainMenuApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Drawer()

    def on_start(self):
        topic = "kivy/#"

        def onConnect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
            mqttc.subscribe(topic, 0)

        def onMessage(client, userdata, msg):
            msg.payload = msg.payload.decode("utf-8")
            print ("[INFO   ] [MQTT        ] topic: " + msg.topic +" msg: "+ msg.payload)
            if msg.topic == "kivy/button":
                userdata['self'].vartext1 = msg.payload

            if msg.topic == "kivy/text":
                userdata['self'].vartext2 = msg.payload

        parameters = {'self': self}
        mqttc = mqtt.Client(client_id="kivy-client", clean_session=True, userdata = parameters)
        mqttc.on_connect      = onConnect 
        mqttc.on_message      = onMessage
        mqttc.connect("10.0.0.104", 1883, keepalive=60, bind_address="")
        mqttc.loop_start() # start loop to process callbacks! (new thread!)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainMenuApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

Think there is missing a `.root` for `userdata['self']` in your problem.

At least for me, it worked when I made the following change.

Replace

```
userdata['self'].vartext2 = msg.payload
```

to

```
userdata['self'].root.vartext2 = msg.payload
```